Lost app software centre
I really don't know what I'm doing and accidentally uninstalled the software centre and all the apps. Can I reinstall this? The only apps that I have are the ones in settings/apps. No Snap-Store. (I was trying to update Snap-Store when I lost everything.) i had used a command in the terminal to remove and reinstall it, but it obviously was the wrong command!. I ran the software updater thinking that it may install the apps, but it hasn't.
Is there a way to refresh ubuntu to reinstall all the programmes/apps?
Thanks settings/appsshowing ubuntu software installer and updater. 

If you are prone to disastrous mistakes, then it might be prudent to provide the detailed, accurate sequence of commands you used in your question above. Use the history command to review what you typed.
